# Fix (CWE-120, CWE-20) detected by Flawfinder

Tags: c, security, flawfinder

I've been asked to analyze some C code with Flawfinder:

```
char * buffer;
size_t len;
// my_fd is a file descriptor
read(my_fd, &len, sizeof(len));
buffer = malloc(len + 1);
read(my_fd, buffer, len);
buffer[len] = '\0';
```

I get the following warnings on the 2 read:

```
test.c:xx:  [1] (buffer) read:
  Check buffer boundaries if used in a loop including recursive loops
  (CWE-120, CWE-20).
test.c:xx:  [1] (buffer) read:
  Check buffer boundaries if used in a loop including recursive loops
  (CWE-120, CWE-20).
```

I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53020336/read-check-buffer-boundaries-if-used-in-a-loop-including-recursive-loops) answer, modifying the function as follows:

```
char * buffer;
size_t len;
// my_fd is a file descriptor
ssize_t ret = read(my_fd, &len, sizeof(len));

if (ret == -1 || ret != sizeof len) {
     buffer = NULL;
} else {
     buffer = malloc(len + 1);
     ret = read(my_fd, buffer, len);
     buffer[ret] = '\0';
}
free(buffer);
```

But the vulnerabilities are still detected. What am I missing?

**Update #1:**

I updated the function according to @4386427 suggestions, checking both `read()` and `malloc()`:

```
char * buffer = NULL;
size_t len;
ssize_t ret = read(my_fd, &len, sizeof(len));

if (ret == sizeof len)
{
     buffer = malloc(len + 1);

     if (buffer != NULL)
     {
          ret = read(my_fd, buffer, len);

          if (ret == len)
          {
               buffer[ret] = '\0';
          }
          free(buffer);
     }
}
```

But nothing has changed, how can i further improve security?

**Update #2**

Because Flawfinder only does pattern check, and because it seems that no more improvements can be applied; at this point I'm marking these errors as false positive.

Comment: Are you sure about the location of the warning? The message mentions usage in a loop which is not present in the code you show.

Comment: Yes, error points directly to the lines containing the `read()` call

Comment: `ret = read(my_fd, buffer, len);` and what happens if this reads return -1 ?

Comment: The second code example could be simplified a bit: `char * buffer = NULL; ... if (ret > 0) { /* Create buffer and read into it */ }`

Comment: I'm assuming that a 2nd read should not generate errors if the 1st one is fine, am I wrong?

Comment: You should not rely on that.

Comment: @LucaBonadia And what makes you think it's safe to assume that? (yes, you are wrong..)

Comment: Right, I'll update the question

Comment: After your update: `if (ret > 0)` is wrong! Must be `if (ret == sizeof len)`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `if (ret > 0)` is not a good idea

Comment: Sorry @4386427 I posted the wrong version of the function, but it does not solve the issue

Comment: @LucaBonadia Your last code snippet is correct.

Comment: Yes but the errors are still detected by Flawfinder (this is why I haven't marked your answer as the correct one)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224087/discussion-between-lucabonadia-and-4386427).

Comment: Probably a "false positive". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59293533/a-flaw-reported-by-flawfinder-but-i-dont-think-it-makes-sense Anyway - you did get some bugs fixed ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I see two places in your last code snippet where you don't handle return values correct. 1) You don't check the `malloc` 2) You don't check the read

Try:

```
char * buffer;
size_t len;
// my_fd is a file descriptor
ssize_t ret = read(my_fd, &len, sizeof(len));

if (ret != sizeof len) {
     buffer = NULL;
} else {
    buffer = malloc(len + 1);
    if (buffer != NULL)        // Check that malloc was ok
    {
         ret = read(my_fd, buffer, len);

         if (ret == -1)        // Check that read was ok
         {
             // error handling....
             //
             // for now just do:
             ret = 0;
         }
         else if (ret != len)
         {
             // Didn't get as much data as expected
             //
             // Add some error handling....
         }
         buffer[ret] = '\0';
    }
}
free(buffer);
```